# Bootstrap date picker Z-index safari

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

Im having trouble with displaying a date picker above a modal in safari, works perfectly in all other browsers

When the date picker is drawn the z-index always reverts to 10, I've tried adding the following code:

```
.datepicker{z-index: 100000!important}
```

yet the z-index is still 10

this is the Jquery code is as folllowed:

```
$("#datepicker2").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    startView: 2
});
```

Any help?

Comment: Please give your code in fiddle

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this

```
.datepicker{z-index: 100000!important}
```

To this

```
#datepicker2{z-index: 100000!important}
```

This way it only affects this exact datepicker. There might be some global styles that overwrite your .datepicker styles.